# In place lightboxing of parts of a web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, yui, lightbox

I'm creating a system to walk users through a web site. To avoid mistakes and to keep the user focused I'd like to darken everything on the page other than what I want them to interact with. I'd also like to do this in place (not in a popup).

The way I approached this was to append a `div` to the `body` and set it's style to:

```
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  -ms-filter:'alpha(opacity=50)';
  filter: alpha(opacity=50)
  z-index: 1000
```

I then set the `z-index` of the element I wanted to highlight/lightbox to be higher than that of the appended `div`. In this case, I set it to be `1001`. For my primary use case, I wanted to highlight a `form`. The problem with this was that only the individual check boxes and other fields became undarkened and clickable. The box containing the form was still dark. Is there any way that I can get entire element including the background to become highlighted?

Comment: just curious, did you set a background color (i assume white) for the div containing the form?

Comment: "opacity < 1" with black color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to be precise without seeing your HTML, but this sounds like a `z-index` issue to me.

[`z-index`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/z-index) only applies to elements that have `position` of either `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed`.  The default is `static`.

Try explicitly setting the positioning for the 'non-working' elements to `relative`.